# Generating a file for download without storing a copy locally on the server

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a web application through Flask, which converts uploaded files into Base64 and stores this in a separate file which the user can then download. 
This can be quite extensive in regards to storage as the file has to be saved once converted and then the user can download it, is it possible to create this file and push it to be downloaded by the user without having to store it locally?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create files on the server and return them for download using a [`Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#response-objects) object.

As an example, returning a text file (taken from a real life web app):

```
@app.route('/account/security/2fa_backup_codes.txt')
@login_required
def backup_codes():
    codes = g.user.tfa_backup.replace(',', '\r\n')
    generator = (cell for row in codes for cell in row)
    return Response(generator, mimetype='text/plain',
        headers={'Content-Disposition':
                 'attachment;filename=2fa_backup_codes.txt'})
```